# Rails's bundle --binstubs on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, bundle

I am reading a tutorial about Ruby on Rails ( http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec:binstubs ) and it suggests using `bundle --binstubs` to eliminate prefixing commands with `bundle exec`. However this doesn't seem to work on Windows, as it is not legal to call an executable from the bin folder without cd-ing to it first.

There is a comment of this article:
http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2011/07/18/stop-typing-bundle-exec/
that says "... I wish it worked on Windows.". I was wondering - is it really not possible to do use this on Windows?

Thanks,

szm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gem [rubygems-bundler](https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler) was made explicitly for this purpose. To quote their readme:

> First,
>
> `gem install rubygems-bundler`
>
> Next, run (once):
>
> `gem regenerate_binstubs`
>
> And you're done!

It works thusly:

> It modifies gem wrappers shebang to load ruby_noexec_wrapper. Then,
>   when you run gem binaries, it takes a look at your working directory,
>   and every directory above it until it can find a Gemfile. If the
>   executable you're running is present in your Gemfile, it switches to
>   using that Gemfile instead (via Bundle.setup).